# Converting a SQL query to SEQUELIZE

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I am trying to wrap my head around creating this sequelize query.

```
SELECT 
    dayofweek(datum) AS DOW, 
    concat(DAY(datum), '-', MONTH(datum)) AS datum, 
    ochtend, 
    middag, 
    avond 
FROM dbt.menus
    ORDER BY datum ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET (variable in sequelize code);
```

I have been able to create 2 separate queries where the 'order by filter' works and 'aliases' work, but not combined.

This is what i currenty have in sequelize

```
const amount = await Menu.count();
const listOfMenu = await Menu.findAll({ 
    order: [['datum', 'ASC']],
    offset: amount - 5,
    limit: 5,
    attributes: {
        include: [
            [
              Menu.sequelize.fn
              (
                "DATE_FORMAT", 
                Menu.sequelize.col("datum"), 
                "%d-%m "
              ),
              "datum",
            ],
          ]
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `fn` twice: in `order` and in `attributes` options:

```js
const datumExpression = Menu.sequelize.fn
              (
                "DATE_FORMAT", 
                Menu.sequelize.col("datum"), 
                "%d-%m "
              )
const listOfMenu = await Menu.findAll({ 
    order: [[datumExpression, 'ASC']],
    offset: amount - 5,
    limit: 5,
    attributes: {
        include: [
            [
              datumExpression,
              "datum",
            ],
          ]
     }
});
```

Also you can combine `findAll` and `count` queries into one `findAndCountAll` and you will get the result with two props: `rows` and `count`:

```js
const { rows: listOfMenu, count: amount } = await Menu.findAndCountAll({ 
    order: [[datumExpression, 'ASC']],
    offset: amount - 5,
    limit: 5,
    attributes: {
        include: [
            [
              datumExpression,
              "datum",
            ],
          ]
     }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This did fix my problem with sorting the dates. But is missing a solution for the `dayofweek(datum) AS DOW,`

Comment: You can always add as many custom attributes with `fn` or `literal` as you wish.